# Separate Event Handler for Reusability

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a simple click handler that will alert its link's `href` as in:

```
<a id="link" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>

$('a#link').on('click', function() {
  alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

How can I separate the function (and how to call it) so that it can be called by another click handler?

```
function showHref() {
  /* What to do here because $(this) won't resolve to <a> anymore. */
}

// I'd like a#another-link to be able to call that same function above.    
<a id="another-link" href="http://www.microsoft.com">Microsoft</a>

$('a#another-link').on('click', /* How to call showHref? */);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
function showHref() {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
}

$('a#link').on('click', showHref);
$('a#another-link').on('click', showHref);
```

In this code, `this` inside the `showHref` *will* refer to the link being clicked, since jQuery makes sure that the link being clicked is the calling context (using `.call()` which you may want to read up on). If, however, you were to manually call `showHref`, `this` would *not* refer to your link.

If you want a definition of `showHref` that you could both call manually, and bind through jQuery, it would probably be neatest to pass the reference as a parameter:

```
function showHref(link) {
    alert($(link).attr('href'));
}
```

In that case, you'd have to adjust your listeners as follows:

```
$('a#link').on('click', function() {
    showHref(this);
});
```

But it is also possible to combine selectors:

```
$('a#link, a#another-link').on('click', function() {
   alert($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: it should of course just be `this.href`, not `$(this).attr('href')`, though ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak: I usually don't mind the jQuery round-trip. `this.className` works in some browsers and not in others, `$(this).attr('class')` works in all. To me, the single greatest benefit of jQuery is not having to deal with different browser implementations. The fact that the particular attribute `href` doesn't happen to have any such inconsistencies in behavior across the major browsers is not a very compelling reason to make an exception to this practice, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the function logic into a reference like this:

```
var handler = function () {
    alert($(this).attr('href'));
};
```

Then you can use that reference to initialize event listeners:

```
$('#link').on('click', handler);
```

Of course, you can reuse that.

```
$('#some_other_link').on('click', handler);
```

Or call that yourself outside of an event handler context (which normally wouldn't make sense if you're fashioning an event handler function --- but it can be done with lambdas in general).

```
handler();
```

But if you want to just trigger the event on an element, you should call the corresponding event trigger function.

```
$('#link').click();
// or
$('#link').trigger('click');
```

Comment: The manual call `handler()` will not, as written, have a reference to the link being clicked as its `this` keyword, and hence will not work.

Comment: @David ~ Exactly. Different uses, different methods.

Comment: @David ~ woops, sorry, when I answered this the OP has not clarified the question further. Let me edit that.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
function showHref() {
  /* What to do here because $(this) won't resolve to <a> anymore. */
}
```

Umm, actually, yes it will.  That's exactly the promise made by DOM events and also event handlers registered with jQuery.

FWIW, the content should just be:

```
alert(this.href)
```

There's really no need to invoke jQuery just to get the element's `href` attribute.